# How can I collectively update & increment multiple elements in a nested array?

Tags: python, mongodb

So I have data (via MongoDB) stored like

```
{
    "idx": something,
    "array": [
        {name: name#1, val: val#1, num: num#1}, 
        {name: name#2, val: val#2, num: num#2}, 
        {name: name#3, val: val#3, num: num#3}
    ]
}
```

I want to update the values and increment the nums of specific elements in the array depending on the name. (For example, let's say I want to set the value of name#1 to val#3 while incrementing its number and setting the value of name #3 to val#4 while incrementing its number.) How would I do that in an update command? Would I have to do multiple update commands where each command filtered based on the array?

Comment: What's the logic? Is there any rule for choosing name#1 = val#3, but name#3 = val#4?? Why not name#3 = val#5?

Comment: No, there are no rules regarding the naming.

Comment: I'm asking how to do it in a MongoDB database.

Comment: You can use a pipeline in `update`.  All the document updates you mentioned could be done in a single pipeline.